# Syntax error - '$this' is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, dreamweaver

I am trying to correct errors in my javascript but I am not finding anything for an error Dreamweaver is labeling as **'$this' is not defined.** Is my syntax missing something?

```
    //contact form
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Put var in front of it.  `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: you shouldn't use $this, use that or self instead, usually $var in js is understood as global (not enforced by language just a convention)

Comment: This should actually still work. It will just put the `$this` in the global scope instead of in the function scope.

Comment: use arrow function to keep the scope: `$.post($(this).attr('action'), (data)=> {
        $(this).prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json')`; and you don't have to declare a variable

Comment: I'd try actually running the code. Dreamweaver might be warning you that you are creating a global variable, since you haven't previously had a `var $this` statement.

Comment: There are best ways to do that.   (1) use var that= $(this); (2) remove the variable while you don't really need it only refer to $(this) directly.

Comment: In this particular case, the `this` pointer changes when he enters the function.  As such he needs to save it to a variable before entering the anonymous function.